# Laravel 5: test return redirect with session

Tags: laravel-5

I have an insert method in Laravel, that return a message

```
if ($update === true) {
            return redirect(route('settings-cloudflare'))
                ->with('success', trans('common.operation_completed_successfully'));
            // validation ok
        } else {
```

How can I test that redirected view has "success" inside?

My test is:

```
    $response = $this->followingRedirects()->actingAs($user)->post(Route('settings-cloudflare-store'),$data);
    dd(session()->all());
```

But `session` doesn't have "success" inside.

This is the `dd` of session:

```
array:3 [
  "_token" => "2jV8sVgRluET9UCng2HzqDYOgSkTVYMqJTT20MsP"
  "_flash" => array:2 [
    "new" => []
    "old" => []
  ]
  "_previous" => array:1 [
    "url" => "http://192.168.1.101/settings/cloudflare"
  ]
]
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/http-tests#assert-session-has

Comment: I did print directly the session, that hasnt my "success" inside...

Comment: so `$response->assertSessionHas('success')` didn't work?

Comment: No, it didn't work. I did print the dd session.. thank you

Comment: @MattKomarnicki No, I don't think I never solved. But the project was abandonated.